# State not updating to the other child component

Tags: reactjs

I have simple login component where the value of the global state will change when the button is clicked. It only updates from the login component. When the button is clicked on the login component, it renders "You are login" and the button will change into "logout" and vice versa. But it does not update from the "about" component

**Login component**

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { AppContext } from "../src/App"

export const Login = () => { 
    
    const value = useContext(AppContext);
    

    const doLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (value.loginStatus) {
            value.setLoginStatus(false)
        } else {
            value.setLoginStatus(true)
        }
    }
    

    return(
        <>
        <h1>{value.loginStatus?"You  are login": "You are not"}</h1>
        <button onClick={(e) => doLogin(e)}>{value.loginStatus?"Login": "logout"}</button>
        </>
        
    )
}
```

**About component**

In about component, not updating.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../src/App";

export const About = () => {
    const value = useContext(AppContext);
    
    return(
        <h1>{value.loginStatus? "You are logged in": "You are not"}</h1>
    )
};
```

**App**

```
import './App.css'
import { useState, createContext } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from '../Pages/Home';
import { About } from '../Pages/About';
import { Login } from '../Pages/Login';



export const AppContext = createContext();
function App() {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      
        <AppContext.Provider value={{loginStatus, setLoginStatus}}>
          <Router>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={ <Home />}></Route>
              <Route path='/about' element={ <About />}></Route>
              <Route path='/login' element={ <Login />}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </AppContext.Provider>

    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have no way to navigate from your login page to the about page in the snippets you provided. Are you just typing `/about` in the address bar? Then the page gets refreshed, and your context is lost.

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks for the help :)))